# I'm trying to implement a lstm model where i need to padding column wise . how to do this?

Tags: lstm, recurrent-neural-network

let I have a list-

```
               task= [ 
                     [  [1,2,3], [2,3,5] ]
                     [  [1,2,3], [2,3,5] , [4,5,6] ]  
                     ]
```

I want to do this as like this one -

```
                task= [ 
                      [  [0,0,0], [1,2,3], [2,3,5]  ]
                      [  [1,2,3], [2,3,5] , [4,5,6] ]  
                      ]
```